# Count the items inside each element respectively

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to figure out how I can get or count the items inside each element respectively. Here is a code below to show you my problem.

Here you can see I have a list element with different number of items. Now what if I want to the get number of items for each element separately, then store them inside a variable so that I can use the value.

The jquery `.length` get the number of items but it adds them all up. Adding a class to the element solves this problem but is there I can do this programmatically instead.

I'm currently building a slider that will apply the width based on the number of items inside the element.

So if slide one has 3 items width 20px, then the total width of the slide would be 60px

And if the second slide has 5 items, then it will total to 100px.

```js
var count = $('.list li').length;

console.log(count);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Select only the `.list` elements, and then use .each to iterate over them and look how many `li` you find inside ...

Comment: So each ul is a list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate on the `list`s using `.each()`, and then inspect the contents of each list, like this:

```js
var lengths = [];
$('.list').each(function() {
  var items = $(this).find('li');
  console.log(items.length);
  lengths.push(items.length); // gather into lengths variable
});
console.log("lengths = [" + lengths + "]");
// You can now use lengths[i] as desired.
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
</ul>
<ul class="list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, question the variable `var count` returns a `NaN` value

Comment: Or in other words how can I use the value stored inside variable `items` outside

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake, I forgot to remove that part. The each() call does not return values, but you can gather them in an array inside the function if you need to. I now edited the answer to use an array,

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, when I meant value I meant the `.length` that is being used in order to count the number of items inside the list.

Comment: See my latest edit, it now gathers the length values.

Answer (score 1):

use  .eq() method and find length.

```js
var count = $('.list').eq(0).find('li').length;
var count1 = $('.list').eq(1).find('li').length;
console.log(count +'-------'+count1);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What if there are more than two lists?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
jQuery( "ul.list" ).each(function( index ) {
            console.log(jQuery(this).children().length);
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to get an array `result` of objects with the `index` and the `count` of `li` elements in all the `ul.lists`:

```js
var result = $.map($('ul.list'), function(el, index) {
  return {
    index: index,
    count: $(el).find('li').length
  };
});

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit different approach of mine here. I would store the length of all the lists in an array and use it whenever I wish to.

```
var list = new Array();
$('.list').each(function(){
    list.push($(this).children().length);
});
```